# Как подключиться через airflow к hdfs, развернутой в docker?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, airflow

Я развернул этот проект https://github.com/Marcel-Jan/docker-hadoop-spark

Выполнил инструкцию "Quick Start Spark (PySpark)" в readme и получил датафрейм, все как надо

Мне нужно сделать тоже самое, но через airflow. Я подключаюсь к спарк сессии и все ок:

```
spark = (SparkSession
            .builder
            # .master('local')
            .master("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")
            .appName("Test")
            .getOrCreate())
```

Но когда пытаюсь достучаться до hadoop, получаю ошибку

```
Call From SPB-379/127.0.1.1 to namenode:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Я понимаю что airflow не видит ip "namenode" и пробовал выполнить такую команду, чтобы получить полный адрес хадупа-
docker inspect  и вывод

```
"Networks": {
                "docker-hadoop-spark_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "namenode",
                        "namenode",
                        "8a06dd5cca57"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "f57164de9f26ef3a1a33c4ee46b24903c0824009ecfeda06f7f45ba9206f6a0a",
                    "EndpointID": "6bf662634c9ef925dc435d8a28364b045ef8b572e22f5c5316257ada2a52cc0d",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.9",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:09",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
```

Но этот ipaddress тоже выдает ошибку. Я не уверен, что двигаюсь в правильном направлении, поэтому буду рад любому фидбеку:)

Answer (score 0):

Каким образом развернут Airflow? Если также в контейнере для Docker и находится в той же сети, что и контейнеры с Hadoop, то последний должен быть виден по имени (`namenode`).